# validation error messages is not working properly flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

So I want to make error messages on the sign-in page, but the messages are not popping up or not working very well on both email and password error messages. Whenever I clicked on the "SIGN IN" button that I made it always go to the next page and it was supposed not to do that. Here is my code:

**SIGN IN FORM**

```
class sign_in_form extends StatefulWidget {
  const sign_in_form({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _sign_in_formState createState() => _sign_in_formState();
}

class _sign_in_formState extends State<sign_in_form> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? email;
  String? password;

  final List<String?> errors = [];

  void addError ({String? error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error)) {
      setState(() {
        errors.add(error);
      });
    }
  }

  void removeError ({String? error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error)) {
      setState(() {
        errors.remove(error);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          errors_form(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
          splash_button(
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState!.save();
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: "Please Enter your email");
        }
        else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: "Please Enter Valid Email");
        }
        return;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: "Please Enter your email");
          return "";
        }
        else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: "Please Enter Valid Email");
          return "";
        }
        return value;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Icon(Icons.email),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value){
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: "Please Enter your password");
        }
        else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removeError(error: "Password is too short");
        }
        return;
      },
      validator: (value){
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: "Please Enter your password");
          return "";
        }
        else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: "Password is too short");
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        hintText: "Enter your password",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 20, 20),
          child: Icon(Icons.lock),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**MY ERROR FORM**

```
class errors_form extends StatelessWidget {
  const errors_form({Key? key, required this.errors,}) : super(key: key);
  final List<String?> errors;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: List.generate(
          errors.length, (index) => form_error_text(errors: errors[index]!)),
    );
  }
  Row form_error_text ({required String errors}) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/icons/Error.svg",
          height: getProportionateScreenWidth(14),
          width: getProportionateScreenWidth(14),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(14)),
        Text(errors),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below example code of error messages handling

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode emailFocus = FocusNode();
  final TextEditingController pswdController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode pswdFocus = FocusNode();
  final _validationKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  int validateEmail(String emailAddress) {
    String patttern =
        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]"
        r"{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]"
        r"{0,253}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$";
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (emailAddress.isEmpty || emailAddress.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(emailAddress)) {
      return 2;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  int validatePassword(String pswd) {
    if (pswd.isEmpty || pswd.length == 0) {
      return 1;
    } else if (pswd != null && pswd.isNotEmpty && pswd.length <= 8) {
      return 2;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
        ),
        title: Text("Example"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Form(
              key: _validationKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  /* Email */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    /* autovalidate is disabled */
                    controller: emailController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 160,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validateEmail(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter your email address";
                      } else if (res == 2) {
                        return "Please enter valid email address";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: emailFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter your email" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15.0,
                  ),

                  /* Password */
                  TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    /* autovalidate is disabled */
                    controller: pswdController,
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                          r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                    ],
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    maxLength: 160,
                    onChanged: (val) {},
                    obscureText: true,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    validator: (value) {
                      int res = validatePassword(value);
                      if (res == 1) {
                        return "Please enter password";
                      } else if (res == 2) {
                        return "Please enter minimum 9 characters";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                    focusNode: pswdFocus,
                    autofocus: false,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorMaxLines: 3,
                      counterText: "",
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                        ),
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                      errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          )),
                      focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1,
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Enter password" ?? "",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _validationKey.currentState.validate();
                if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
                  emailFocus.requestFocus();
                } else if (pswdController.text.isEmpty ||
                    pswdController.text.length <= 8) {
                  pswdFocus.requestFocus();
                }
              },
              child: Text("Validate"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```